# Помогите настроить WebDAV

Tags: nginx, сервер

Привет всем!

[image: схема]

Хочу сделать такую схему, подобную той, что использует `Yandex.disk`, если вам так понятнее будет.

Короче, есть сервер на ОС `linux ubuntu server`. В ней есть некоторое количество пользователей. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователи могли получить доступ к своей учетной записи в системе не только по `ssh`, или локальному входу на сервере, но и через `webdav`. При этом, авторизация должна происходить с использованием `/etc/passwd`, и каждый авторизовавшийся через `webdav` мог бы читать и писать в свой каталог.

В общем, с авторизацией по `/etc/passwd` Я разобрался - тут нужно было искать информацию о том, как устроен `PAM`, и что это такое. В итоге, аутентификация работает, но как сделать так, чтобы при входе по `webdav` и успешной аутентификации, пользователь мог бы не только читать, но еще и писать в свою папку Я не смог. Собственно, это меня очень печалит. Если дать на каталог пользователя права 777, то примонтировав вебдав каталог, файлы в нем можно писать, создавать новые файлы, но при этом они создаются с правами веб сервера.

В качестве `webdav` сервера используется `nginx`, и модифицированный модуль `webdav`, который умеет то, что не умеет стандартный модуль вебдав. Подкупил своей простотой настройки, и вроде как говорят, он нереально шустро работает. Но как Я понял, у него нет возможности каждого пользователя авторизовывать с его собственными правами.

Апача боюсь, т.к. его конфиги вводят меня в ступор, хотя в нем, говорят, есть чудесный модуль `mpm-itk`, который вроде как позволит мне сделать то, что Я хочу.

Какие варианты еще можете посоветовать?

Comment: я не думаю, что обычный модуль nginx pam вас спасет, вам нужно после авторизации pam  форкнуть nginx с новым uid/gid, а этот модуль видимо так не делает.

Answer (score 1):

*pam_ldap* и т.д. - это, по отзывам на http://forum.nginx.ru, тормоз для *NGINX*. 
Сам не проверял.

А про *WebDAV* + *NGINX* с многопользовательской рекурсивной авторизацией и всякими *DAV-хомяками*: вот мой open source под MIT, может, Вам подойдёт:

http://ihome.itcod.com/max/projects/itcod-disk/README.txt

**Обновление**

В теме так и не прозвучал вроде ответ на вопрос.

> но при этом они создаются с правами веб сервера

Я бы так попробовал куснуть эту изначальную задачку.

1. Поместите пользователей `webdav` в группу `nginx`.
2. Установите в конфиге webdav ресурса `dav_access` `user:rw group:rw;`
3. Сделайте `chmod -R 775` или `770` по вкусу для хомяков webdav-пользователей.

imho кривовато както, зато решаемо без форка nginx с правами юзера.

Answer (score 0):

Owncloud - в комплекте модуль webdav + доступ к своим докам извне... Активно используется уже 2 года, проблем не замечено...Вторым вариантом можно рассматривать обычные сервисы Samba, она все это умеет, но вариант первый красив, функционален и короче посмотрите...

Comment: Здравствуйте! Эта штуковина требует апача. Не хочу с апачем связываться.

Comment: Ну и напрасно, ничего в нем страшного нет, все работает по дефолту